# User not being updated as I login using protected route in react route v6

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I am trying to log a user in. I have a login component which takes the credentials and then I am using redux toolkit to store the state and the verification and everything is done in userSlice. I have a protected route which should check if the user is logged in or not and if the user is not logged in then it should not navigate to the recipe page which I have. when I try to access the user from the protected route component using useSelecter hook it returns empty on the first render but on the second render it does return user but the login still fails. in the redux dev tools the state is being updated just fine. is there a way where I can get the user object on the first render from the protected route component. (As you can see I am using the useEffect hook and have the dependency array too).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Below are my code:

Login.js -- this file is responsible for taking in the credentials and then dispatching an action and updating the state using useDispatch.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { loginUser } from '../../features/users/userSlice';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const  user  = useSelector(state => state.user.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()


  return (
    <div>
        <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={() => {
        dispatch(loginUser({email, password}))
        navigate('/recipes')
      }}>submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ProtectedRoute.js -- This component makes sure if the user is not authenticated he must not be able to login

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  const [ activeUser, setActiveUser ] = useState(false)
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user.isLoading) {
      user.success ? setActiveUser(true) : setActiveUser(false)
      console.log('active user: ' + activeUser)
    }
  }, [user])

  return (
    activeUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
  )
}
```

app.js -- This component has all the routes including the protected route.

```
import React from "react";
import Recipes from "./components/recipes/recipes";
import Login from "./components/users/Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./utils.js/ProtectedRoute";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" index element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/login" />}/>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route element={<Recipes/>} path="/recipes" />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

userSlice.js -- since I am using redux toolkit hence I have slices for different things. This has reducers which have user state.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const loginUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/login';
const signupUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/signup';

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('user/loginUser', async (data) => {
    const response = await axios.post(loginUrl, data);
    return response;
})

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', async (data) => {
    const response = await axios.post(signupUrl, data);
    return response;
})

const initialState = {
    user: {},
    isLoading: true
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getPassword: (state, action) => {
            const password = action.payload
            console.log(password)
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        },
        [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.user = action.payload.data
        },
        [loginUser.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        },
        [signupUser.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        },
        [signupUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.user = action.payload.data
        },
        [signupUser.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
        },
    }
})

export const { getPassword } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the login handler is issuing both actions "simultaneously".

```js
onClick={() => {
  dispatch(loginUser({ email, password })); // <-- log user in
  navigate('/recipes');                     // <-- immediately navigate
}}
```

The navigation action to the protected route occurs prior to the user being authenticated the redux state being updated.

To resolve the login handler should wait for successful authentication ***then*** redirect to the desired route.

```js
const loginHandler = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await dispatch(loginUser({ email, password })).unwrap();
    if (/* check response condition */) {
      navigate("/recipes", { replace: true });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // handle any errors or rejected Promises
  }
};

...


onClick={loginHandler}
```

See [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results) for more details.

You may also want to simplify the `ProtectedRoute` logic to not require an extra rerender *just* to get the correct output to render. All the route protection state can be derived from selected redux state.

```
export default function ProtectedRoute() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (user.isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
   }

  return user.success ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```